# Ohai: unable to get network attributes via ssh

Tags: ssh, ohai-gem

I have several servers running centOS 6 and centOS 7. I am working in an inventory system, and for that I am using ohai, which is installed in all the machines.

When I do `ssh myuser@myserver.com ohai` it returns a json object with all the information but the network section empty.
However, if I ssh into the server and I run `ohai` I get the proper network attributes.

Someone has any idea what can be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved, the problem was that ohai needs root rights to check the nics properties.